# how to prevent unsetting ReadOnly flag of a file using java?

Tags: java, file, readonly

I 've created a servlet to let users download a file . When the file is downloaded , I want it to be ReadOnly so that the user can't modify its content . So I've used the ***java.io.File*** class :

`downloadFile.setWritable(false);`

but I realized that the user can unset the read only flag after downloading the file .

What can I to prevent unsetting the read only flag?

Comment: I don't think that's possible. After downloading a file, it is under the user's system's control and your server has no more influence on it.

Answer (score 0):

> I've created a servlet to let users download a file.

That servlet will be running on the web server. It's not running on the user's local computer - so it can't change anything about the user's local file system. Even your `downloadFile.setWritable(false)` won't operate on the user's local file system - the file will be saved by the browser, and the user gets to do whatever they want with it.

Even if you *are* running some app separately to your service, it would be not only hard, but pretty unfriendly to create a file which the user couldn't touch on their own system. You *could* try to run your app as a separate user, and give appropriate permissions to both the file and the directory it runs in - but then if the user has access to an administrator account, they'd still be able to override that.

Answer (score 0):

As a user has downloaded your file, he can do anything with this file. If you are concerned about authenticity of the downloaded file, then consider [data signing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/security/apisign/).

Sign your file using key, that is stored on the server and which is not available to end user.

To verify the file authenticity implement a servlet with functionality described in the link above.